# ImageView not Clickable in Dialog Fragment

Tags: android

I open a dialog on click of my list item. The dialog has 2 image views and on textview. The issue is imageview is not getting clicked. Only textview is clickable.

Below is the xml for dialog:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/pledge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/uncheck" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/pledge"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/pledge"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/pledge" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/points"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/pledge"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/uncheck" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/pledge"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/points"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/points" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/confirm"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/points"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/confirm"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Confirm" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Only TextView with `@+id/confirm` is clickable, but I want to imageviews(`@+id/pledge & @+id/points`) defined above to be clickable too.

Below is class

```
public class ConfirmDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    Boolean pointsChecked = false;
    Boolean pledgeChecked = false;
    ImageView pledge,points;

    @Override
    public void dismiss() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.dismiss();
    }

    public ConfirmDialogFragment() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onAttach(activity);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDetach();

    }


    @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
        dialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getActivity();
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity()
                 .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.confirm_dialog_fragment,null);
                dialog.setContentView(v);

        final ImageView pledge = (ImageView) v
                .findViewById(R.id.pledge);
        pledge .setClickable(true);
        final ImageView points = (ImageView) v
                .findViewById(R.id.points);
        points.setClickable(true);
        TextView confirm = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.confirm);
        confirm.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                AppSession sInstance = AppSession.getInstance();
                sInstance.setConfirm(true);
                dismiss();
                Fragment fragment = new ListFragment();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                if (fragmentManager .getBackStackEntryCount() > 0){
                    fragmentManager .popBackStack();
                }
                ft.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();

            }
        });
        pledge.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if (pledgeChecked) {
                    pledge.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.uncheck);
                    pledgeChecked = false;

                } else {
                    pledge.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.check);
                    pledgeChecked = true;
                }

            }
        });

        points.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (pointsChecked) {
                    points.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.uncheck);
                    pointsChecked = false;

                } else {
                    points.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.check);
                    pointsChecked = true;
                }
            }
        });



        return dialog;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

}
```

I have tried many options making clickable=true in xml and setting clickable in code too but nothing seem to be working. I am not sure if I am missing something as I have done similar things in past but somehow struggling for quite long now. Please advise.

Comment: did you try printing some message inside listener for the imageview. May be System.out.println("clicked");?

Comment: Thanks. Just checked as suggested and its working. I mean going inside my clickListener but somehow not changing the image.

Comment: Try to debug your code and check out flags.

Comment: Replace setBackgroundResource() to setImageResource();

Comment: @Haresh : Thanks. I changed this as suggested in answer below and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the XML file, you are setting the image as **source**. Then, you change the image in the code programmatically by changing the **background**, but the **source** will still be there and hide the **background** completely.
Try using

```
        points.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (pointsChecked) {
                points.setImageResource(R.drawable.uncheck);
                pointsChecked = false;

            } else {
                points.setImageResource(R.drawable.check);
                pointsChecked = true;
            }
        }
    });
```

Edit: By the auto-generated comment I see that you are using Eclipse. I highly recommend you to try Android Studio. I recently switched an I think it is way better.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You saved my day. I think there are still so much to learn concept wise. Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

```
points.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.check)
```

Comment: What kind of answer is this supposed to be?